# Passing username and password from non-web clients to RestController Service and Retrieving it in Service

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, apache-httpclient-4.x

A legacy java application deployed on Internet is trying to communicate to a AuthenticationService which is Spring Security based application and on Intranet. The AuthenticationService authenticates any user when username and password is sent. The client code is:

```
    public static void ApacheHttpClient(String userID, String userPWD){
            CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userID, userPWD);
            provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
              .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
              .build();
            String URL_SECURED_BY_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION = "http://localhost:8080/abc/login";
            try {

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(
                  new HttpGet(URL_SECURED_BY_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION));
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine()
                  .getStatusCode();
              System.out.println("Response Status Code : "+statusCode);
              HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
} catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

The AuthenticationService code for accepting the username and password and authenticating. Here, String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization"); is always coming null

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc")
public class Authenticate {

     @Autowired
        private LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            if(auth != null && auth.length() > 6){
                String userpassEncoded = auth.substring(6);  
                // Decode it, using any base 64 decoder  
                sun.misc.BASE64Decoder dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();  
                String userpassDecoded= new String(dec.decodeBuffer(userpassEncoded));
                System.out.println(" userpassDecoded = "+userpassDecoded);
             }
           } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }

           }
```

Generally it has been recommended to use HTTP Basic or Digest Authentication. I want to understand the approach to send and retrieve the username/password from non-web based app to the service. Like should login be a POST method and username and password be passed as queryparam or pathparam etc

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are several things going on here.

1. Your ApacheHttpClient would work if your AuthenticationService was correctly setup. 
   So let's assume that you believe your AuthenticationService works using Spring Security.
   Please do:

`curl -i http://localhost:8080/abc/login`

Do you see a response that looks like this?

`HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Spring Security Application"`

If you do not see the `WWW-Authenticate` header. Then your AuthorizationService is not set up to handle basic authentication. You didn't configure Spring Security to do Basic authentication for you.

You see, an application that is setup for Basic authentication shall automatically challenge the client (like browser or your HttpClient) with a 401 response and a header.

2. Let's assume that you don't want Spring Security to protect you endpoint.

In this scenario, you can configure your HttpClient to always send the `Authorization` header upon ever request (instead of waiting for the challenge like described in 1.)

The code would look something like this:

```java
public static String ApacheHttpClient(String userID,
                                    String userPWD,
                                    String url,
                                    boolean preempt) throws Exception {
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userID, userPWD);
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    if (preempt) {
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        authCache.put(HttpHost.create(url), new BasicScheme());
        context.setCredentialsProvider(provider);
        context.setAuthCache(authCache);
    } else {
        builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider);
    }
    HttpClient client = builder.build();
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url), context);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Response Status Code : " + statusCode);
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } finally {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

I've created some samples for you to play around with

```
git clone https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community.git
cd spring-security-community
./gradlew :spring-security-community-samples-basic-authentication-client:bootRun
```

First visit the non-secure page: http://localhost:8080/non-secure

Then visit the secure page: http://localhost:8080/secure

Enter `user/password` as your credentials and hit refresh a few times

I've also added the code for your [client](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/3587c8e3fc164b0aa417bbe77c17132682f02daf/samples/basic-authentication-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/BasicAuthorizationClient.java?ts=4#L20), and how to [test it](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/3587c8e3fc164b0aa417bbe77c17132682f02daf/samples/basic-authentication-client/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/BasicHttpClientTest.java?ts=4#L32)

Comment: Hi @Filip AuthenticationService  is working perfectly fine because if I hard code my username and password the Service Authenticates me and returns my ldap details. Also, I am getting 200 OK response in client if I call the service by hard coding username and password. I want some tips to pass credentials from the client and how to handle them in service in better way.

Comment: hi @Pan - take a look at the sample project I put together for you. It should explain everything, but you have to really take a look. You're getting a 200OK if you hard code because you haven't really setup Basic authentication that supports the 401 response challenge that your client expects.

You also haven't said that I tried your `ApacheHttpClient` code that I posted, and I set `preempt=true` and it worked again.

When writing an application that utilizes Spring Security, you don't have to do any basic auth yourself. It's all done for you. For example if you change:

Comment: Take a look at my [sample controller](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/81ca49e14968368196472a822eed506f19b27fdc/samples/basic-authentication-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/SampleAppController.java?ts=4#L58-L59). I don't have to parse basic authentication header. Spring Security does it for me.

Comment: httpBasic() is configured and I am not getting any error 401 response using curl -i http://localhost:8080/abc/login. But,  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid HTTP host: http://localhost:8080/abc/secure error is thrown at line authCache.put(HttpHost.create(url), new BasicScheme()); at org.apache.http.HttpHost.create(HttpHost.java:122)      when I set url="http://localhost:8080/abc/secure"

Comment: hi Pan, first add *http://* to your URL, if that still doesn't work that may be different versions of the HttpClient library? Please review this [test](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/3587c8e3fc164b0aa417bbe77c17132682f02daf/samples/basic-authentication-client/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/BasicHttpClientTest.java#L57-L68) (maybe run it yourself)